# limit access to servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, restriction

I have a gateway sevlet that forward users to many servlets that processes tasks.

each users must go first through the gateway servlet then it forwards them to the proper servlet. 
I create a RequestDispatcher and execute it's forward function to the proper servlet.

the problem is that all the servlets are publicly available so they user can actually go and execute any servlets they want.

I want to allow access only to the gateway servlet and to restrict access to all others. but of course to allow the gateway to forward to the servlets.

how can it be done?

thank you!

using apache tomcat 7

Comment: you can use Filters for this purpose

Comment: can you provide more info?

Comment: This can help http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: do let me know how you implement it, I also want to know for my learning

Comment: There is an example on SO servlet filters wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Answer (score 4):

Using filter to check that the current user is logged in, you'll need to write the method userIsLoggedIn() yourself, by checking session attributes:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

      if (userIsLoggedIn()) {

        //process request normally, pass up the filter chain to the servlet:
        chain.doFilter(req, res);  

      } else {

        //go to login screen instead
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getRequestDispatcher("login");
        dispatcher.forward( request, response );
      }
  }
}
```

In you web.xml, you'll need to declare your filter:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     com.foo.LoginFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```